# Deleting the last part of a string if its longer than 14 letter

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I have a function which gives random Playernames which are sometimes longer than 14 letters. If that happens i want to delete the last characters so its 14 letters long and add "..." to it

Thats what I got so far. I tried substring too but it didnt work as well.
Thanks for helping

```
var playername;
function delString(){
    if (playername.length >= 14){
        var rest = playername.length - 14;
        playername.slice(0, playername.length -rest);
        playername = playername + "...";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just code a function that gives out a 14-character random username ?

Comment: Hint why replace "didn't work" for you, **string is *immutable***

Comment: See the linked question's answers, substituting `substring` or `slice` for `replace`.

Comment: I dont know when i use slice it copies the part after the 14. character and pastes it behind the string and substring just doesnt do anything

Comment: Operations on strings create new strings. You need to capture the returned string from the operation and work with that. `var newString = playername.slice(0, playername.length -rest);`

Comment: See working code here: https://repl.it/OBz4/1

Comment: @NichtEric: *"I dont know when i use slice it copies the part after the 14. character and pastes it behind the string"* Not in the code above it doesn't. *"...and substring just doesnt do anything..."* Again: See the linked question. Both `slice` and `substring` *return* a new string with the change, they don't change the one you call it on.

Comment: Ok thank you all i got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried substring too but it didnt work as well

**No** it works, when you use `substring()` it will return a new `string` and doesn't affect the original one, so you need to assign this result in your old string.

This is how it should be implemented:

```
function delString(name){
    if (name.length >= 14){
        name = name.substring(0, 13);
        name += "...";
    }
    return name;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var playername = "I am longer than 14 chars";
function delString(name){
    if (name.length >= 14){
        name = name.substring(0, 13);
        name += "...";
    }
    return name;
}

console.log(delString(playername));
```

Comment: What about just `return (backticks)${name.slice(0, 13)}...(backticks)`

Comment: @Kinduser That will add `...` every time, and 0,13 only gets you 13 chars. OP wants 14

Comment: @mhodges I meant it to be inside the `if` condition.

Comment: @Kinduser Yes, it's a possible option to use `${name.slice(0, 13)}...` as well.